# Upgrade Current Target For Iphone Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am trying to upgrade my app so that it looks normal on the ipad.  I created a new Target, and then went to upgrade current target for iphone.  It created a Resources-iPad folder but it is empty.  I don't see any new files either.  Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be selecting 'upgrade current target' on your existing iphone target. Creating a new target first will create an updated version of that, which will be empty.

Comment: Oh okay thanks, for some reason it wouldn't let me select upgrade current until after I made a second target, but it's working now